# SSIS Foreach Loop with visual feedback

Tags: sql-server, foreach, ssis, visual-studio-2005

I have a foreach loop container in my SSIS package which iterates about 30 .mdb (Access 2000) files.

These files can be quite large (up to 1GB), so I would like some sort of 'visual feedback' to show which file is currently being iterated, either as a file name or as a 'currently on x out of y files'.

Is there any way to dynamically show this during execution of a package?
Pehaps dynamically updating the name of a box?

I am using SQL Server / Visual Studio 2005

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a script task at the beginning inside your `foreach` loop, select `Visual Basic`, select which variables you want to monitor as ReadOnlyVariables, then replace the default `Public Sub Main()` with this code (edit: also included `Enum ScriptResults` code per request):

```
Enum ScriptResults
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
End Enum

Public Sub Main()
    Dim msg As String = ""
    For Each Variable As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable In Dts.Variables
        msg = msg & "--" & Variable.Name & "|| " & Variable.Value.ToString() & "||"
    Next

    Dts.Events.FireInformation(-1, "", msg, String.Empty, -1, False)
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

The progress tab will then log the variables at the start of each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm getting a few errors however:

`Variable.Value` - _Option Strict On Prohibits operands of type_ Object for '&'`

`ScriptResults` - _Name Script Results is not declared_

Comment: Updated my answer to get rid of that first error (`.ToString()`); the second error suggests that you also deleted the `Enum ScriptResults` which is in the code by default -- is that the case?

Comment: The install was managed by a separate team so I can only assume. The final SSIS package will be uploaded to a server where I don't have admin rights so I won't be able to add any additional files. Any way to add the `Enum ScriptResults' via a class in the script?

Comment: Updated my answer to include the enum code.  It should all go in the same script task.